# Ruby on Rails: Model tell Controller that search query was invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I get a search query, my model checks to make sure it's in the right format. If it's not, I want, instead of displaying the search results, to display a message saying "bad search format". How do I do this?

Controller:

```
  def search
    @students = Student.super_search(params[:super_search])

   # if (INVALID_FLAG == true) ???
   #   make error message...   ???
     if (@students.present?)
       @students = @students.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

And my model:

```
  def self.super_search(super_search)
    if super_search =~ /MY_SPECIAL_REGEX/
      # get and return search results
    else
      # set INVALID_FLAG
    end
  end
```

Comment: You would be better off pulling out this search functionality into its own class, say `StudentSuperSearch`, then its validity could be a flag on the instance itself (e.g. `@student_search = StudentSuperSearch.new(params[:super_search]); if @student_search.valid? ....`)

Comment: What have you tried regarding your error flag?  You could use a return to send a sprecific setting - you could check the length of @students - if it's not zero it should have been a valid search?

Comment: @MageeWorld a valid search could return zero results. For example a search for a student named 'Zaphod Beeblebrox' would be a valid search by name but probably won't return any students.

Comment: Valid searches could return zero students. What I tried doing was just return the string "invalid" when I encounter an invalid search query. It's a bit odd setting @students equal to the string "invalid", but it actually seems to work. Not entirely satisfied with this solution, so I'll continue reading here to see what other ideas there are.

Comment: If there are search criteria that are invalid - you should determine that before performing the search don't you think?  Determine if valid search criteria has been entered and if not, then render the search page again with the error message? (That's what I'd do).  How will they know their input was wrong if they aren't told?

Comment: @ineedahero what if any objections did you have to my suggested solution? This will remove the business logic of searching from the model and allow a very flexible way of handling the response to an invalid search

Comment: I greatly recommend making a model `StudentSearch` backed by Active Model. You'll be able to specify validations run prior to executing search (just like Active Record validations before database operations). Please take a look at [The Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw an exception in model, and catch it in controller :

```
# controller
  def search
    begin
      @students = Student.super_search(params[:super_search])
      # check if not empty
      # paginate

    rescue ArgumentError
      # set flash error or warning
      # display expected syntax
      # redirect back to search
    end
  end

# model
  def self.super_search(super_search)
    if super_search =~ /MY_SPECIAL_REGEX/
      # get and return search results
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid query"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Maybe a custom error, `class SearchError < StandardError;end`, just in case some part of the code stack throws an `ArgumentError` you don't want this catch to swallow it up